# Powershell Register-Object

Tags: powershell

I have a problem in running the below Powershell script in console.

```
function startMonitor {

  $null = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject ([Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents]) -EventName "SessionSwitch" -Action {
    switch($event.SourceEventArgs.Reason) {
    'SessionLock'    
    { 
        ---------do something----   
    }    
    'SessionUnlock'  
    { 
        --------do something----
     }
     }
   }
}
startMonitor
```

When I run this in powershell ISE it works fine and output is as expected. When the session is locked or unlocked, output is generated perfectly.

But I want to run this as a script that starts up during logon.

I put this script in the startup folder as

```
powershell.exe -noexit -windowstyle hidden "E:\sources\lock.ps1"
```

The script runs fine. But, it does not generate the output (the other functions in this code generates output properly, except this function). When I try the command (without the switch -windowstyle):

```
 Get-EventSubscriber
```

Shows that event is registered.

How do I run this script using the powershell.exe -noexit?

I am unable to use task scheduler for this purpose because of limitations in my environment.

Comment: What command do you use to generate output?

Comment: Output is just a text piped to a text file.

Answer (score 1):

In order to run in background you have to keep it within a loop and check for events, test with this little example...

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Diagnostics")
# ------ init ------
function Start-mySession {
$null = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject ([Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents]) -EventName "SessionSwitch" -Action {
add-Type -AssemblyName System.Speech
$synthesizer = New-Object -TypeName System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer
switch($event.SourceEventArgs.Reason) {
    'SessionLock'    { $synthesizer.Speak("Lock!") }
    'SessionUnlock'  { $synthesizer.Speak("Unlock!") }
    }
  }
}

# ------ stop ------
function End-mySession {
    $events = Get-EventSubscriber | Where-Object { $_.SourceObject -eq [Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents] } 
    $jobs = $events | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Action
    $events | Unregister-Event
    $jobs | Remove-Job
}

# ===== keep process in alive for 10 hours =====
[TimeSpan]$GLOBAL:timeout = new-timespan -Hours 10
$GLOBAL:sw = [diagnostics.stopwatch]::StartNew()
while ($GLOBAL:sw.elapsed -lt $GLOBAL:timeout){
    [Array]$GLOBAL:XX_DEBUG_INFO += "DEBUG: initialize debug!"
    # Loop
    Start-mySession
    start-sleep -seconds 10
    #.. do something, or check results
    End-mySession
   }
# teardown after timeout
Write-Output "INFO: $( get-date -format "yyyy-MM-dd:HH:mm:ss" ) : $env:USERNAME : Timeout (logout/timout)"
End-mySession
```

Comment: Why should Register-ObjectEvent need to be in a loop? The event engine should execute the code when the event fires. Can you explain?